# How to use synchronize method with WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

I'm using [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) and am trying to use the `synchronize` method like so:

```
$mech->get('http://example.com/wp-login.php');
$mech->submit_form( with_fields => {log => 'admin', pwd => 'password'});
$self->synchronize( 'DOMContentLoaded', sub {print Dumper($self->title()); });
exit;
```

The title of the newly loaded page prints but then the script just hangs. It never exits. What am I missing?

Comment: `DOMConentLoaded` should be `DOMContentLoaded`. Also, note that the callback that you supply should generally be an action (such as a call to `click`) that will give rise to the given event. Clearly a simple `print` statement won't do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to wait for the page to load before taking the next action without a `sleep` command.

Comment: The next action is to check the title of the page to see if the login was successful. If I don't `sleep` it returns the title of the login page.

Comment: @StevieD: Try putting the call to `submit_form` inside the anonymous subroutine and moving the `print` to after the `synchronize` call. That's at least the way it's supposed to work. I can't write the code for you as I'm on a tablet

Comment: @StevieD What came out of this? I'd be curious to know whether the answers work, as they do for me.

Answer (score 2):

The subroutine that you pass to `synchronize` is meant to do something that kicks off an update to the browser page. `synchronize` calls it and then waits for the event you have specified before it returns

Clearly your `print` statement won't change the web page at all, so no events will fire and your code will be suspended indefinitely

I suggest you put the call to `submit_form` in the subroutine you pass to `synchronize`. That at least stands a chance of causing `DOMContentLoaded` to fire

It would look like this

```
$mech->get('http://example.com/wp-login.php');

$mech->synchronize('DOMContentLoaded', sub {
    $mech->submit_form( with_fields => { log => 'admin', pwd => 'password' });  
});

print Dumper $self->title;
```

Comment: This is something I have already tried and the same thing happens: the new page gets loaded and then the script just hangs.

Comment: @StevieD: Then it's really hard to know what to suggest. Can you tell us the name of the site so that I can test?

Comment: It's just a generic WordPress site. I can't give you the login credentials for it, however.

Answer (score 2):

**Short**   Two solutions below -- Don't specify the event to wait for (so that its default list is used), or use `click` method which does wait on its own, instead of `submit_form`.

---

I see the same problem with `form_submit`, and with the `synchronize` method. Either the next call still gets the page being submitted, or the script hangs with `synchronize` (used, correctly, as in [Borodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36245219/4653379)). I test with a site which does a bit of work as a form is submitted.

Wrapping calls in `synchronize` is borne with some subtleties.  What events are fired or not is not clear and can also be affected (earlier in the code). I found that the code works when no events are specified in the call, and the default list of `events()` is thus checked for.

```
mech->synchronize( sub { 
    $mech->submit_form( with_fields => { log => 'admin', pwd => 'password' } );
});
$mech->save_content('after_submit.html');
```

The following call gets the correct page.

---

The documentation never mentions waiting with `form` methods, so some synchronization is needed. However, the [`click`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-click_$name_[,$x_,$y]_)) method *does wait*, by default (one can change that with `synchronize` option).

So I found this to solve the problem as well: Fill the form and `click` it.

```
# Get the page with the form
$mech->fields( log => 'admin', pwd => 'password' );
$mech->click( name => 'Login' );  # whatever the name is  
$mech->save_content('after_submit.html');
```

The next call after `click` gets the actual next page.

In case the form has no name on `<input>`, for example, this works as well

```
$mech->click_button(input => 'submit');
```