# going to a javascript link with mechanize-firefox

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

There is a link on a page, and I want to go to it but it just a javascript command. How with mechanize do I go to the link?

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#21;ctl54$cphMainContent$resultsGrid$ctl54$ctl25$ctl62$ctl13&#24;,&#56;&#56;)"><span>abc</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the page and its HTML and JS one can only guess. Note that the `follow_link()` methods don't work with JS links. The method below does, but of course I cannot test without the page.

Probably the best bet is to get link(s) as DOM object(s) for the `click` method

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
# Get to your page with the link(s)
my $link = find_link_dom( text_regex => 'abc' );   # Or use find_all_links_dom()
$link->click();  
# $mech->click( { dom => $link } )  # works as well
```

There are also `text` and `text_contains` relevant options (instead of `text_regex`), along with a number of others. Note that `click` method will wait, on a list of events, before returning. See for example [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243320/how-to-use-synchronize-method-with-wwwmechanizefirefox/36258748#36258748). This is critical for pages that take longer to complete.

See docs for [`find_link_dom()`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Efind_link_dom%28_%options_%29) and [`click`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Eclick%28_$name_[,$x_,$y]_%29) methods.  They aren't very detailed or rich in examples but do provide enough to play with and figure it out.

If you need to interrogate links use [`find_all_links_dom()`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Efind_all_links_dom_%options), which returns an array or a reference to array (depending on context) of Firefox's DOM as [`MozRepl::RemoteObject`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.39/lib/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm) instances.

```
my @links_dom = find_all_links_dom( text_contains => 'abc' );

# Example from docs for find_link_dom()
for my $ln (@links_dom) {
    print $ln->{innerHTML} . "\n"
}
```

See the page for [MozRepl::RemoteObject](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.39/lib/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm) to see what you can do with it. If you only need to find out which link to click the options for `find_link_dom()` should be sifficient.

---

This has been tested only with a toy page, that uses `__doPostBack` link, with `<span>` in the link.

Comment: using find_all_links_dom how do I loop through the links and see data on them?

Comment: @Bill  `find_all_links_dom()` returns an array of DOM objects, on which you can invoke suitable methods.  So you set up a normal loop, like `for my $dobj (@links) {}` and call whatever is suitable for each, depending on how you need to disambiguate them. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Bill  Updated the answer.